# Acquire full prefix for a component clientId inside naming containers with JSF 2.0

Tags: java, jsf, reference, components, jsf-2

I am updating a component via AJAX in JSF:

```
<h:form>
    <h:outputLink>Click me
        <f:ajax event="click" render=":messages" />
    </h:outputLink>
</h:form>

<h:messages id="messages" globalOnly="true" />
```

As the `<h:messages />` resides outside `<h:form />` I have to prefix the ID with colon (`:`). This works.

However, if I put this same code into a component and include that component into my page, the code fails. The reason is that `:messages` declaration refers to the root of the component hierarchy, while the `<h:messages />` component that I want to update actually resides under my custom component, which resides under the page (so the location is of style `:myComponent:messages`.

Inside my component, how can I achieve the correct prefix to the `<h:messages />` component? I know that I can manually assign ID to my component, and use that to prefix the reference (like `:#{cc.attrs.id}:messages`). However, I don't know at which level of component hierarchy this component lies, so the required prefix might even be something like `:foo:bar:x:y:messages`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Seems like you can access the current prefix via Expression Language (EL) implicit objects (`cc` and `component`):

- `cc.clientId` returns current *composite* component's prefix
- `component.clientId` returns prefix for any current component.

For example, in a page, call some component via

```
<myComponent id="foo">
```

Inside this component, one can fetch the client IDs like this:

```
<h:outputText id="bar">
   <p>ClientId for the composite component: #{cc.clientId}</p>
   <p>ClientId for current any component: #{component.clientId}</p>
</h:outputText>
```

The following should print out as:

```
ClientId for the composite component: foo
ClientId for current any component: foo:bar
```

I got the pointer from blog post [JSF: working with component identifiers (id/clientId)](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/10/jsf-working-with-component-identifiers.html). It states that this is a new feature for JSF 2.0. Before that one had to fetch the ID programmatically from a backing bean.

Answer (score 0):

@Tuukka Mustonen, thank you for your answer.

And if we need access some another id from the same "place" we could use:

```
<h:outputScript name="js/my-script.js"/>
<h:form id="myForm">
    <h:inputText id="aaa"
        onkeyup="myJSFunction(this.id)"
        value="..."
    />
    <h:inputText id="bbb"
        onkeyup="myJSFunction(aaa.id)"
        value="..."
    />
    <h:inputText id="ccc"
        onkeyup="myJSFunction('#component.parent.clientId.concat(':ccc')}')"
        value="..."
    />
    <h:inputText id="ddd"
        onkeyup="myJSFunction('#component.parent.clientId.concat(':aaa')}')"
        value="..."
    />
</h:form>
```

JavaScript function:

```
function myJSFunction(message) {
    window.alert(message)
}
```

Output on dialog window:

1) myForm:aaa

2) *null*

3) myForm:ccc

4) myForm:aaa

Note: so the 1st and 3th have the same output.