# JSF resource versioning

Tags: jsf, tomcat, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to put versioning around the resources in an application.

If I do like this resources/js/1_0_0/mainscript.js

It does not work. It says RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND

but when I do like this

resources/js/mainscript.js/1_0_0.js

It works. I do not like the way it is organized in the second way. First one looks cool. Any Idea?

I am using Tomcat 7.0, JSF 2.0.9

Update: I was checking primefaces-2-2.1.jar. Since when I checked the page source, I saw this
/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=2.2.1">

Then I looked at META-INF/resources/primefaces/jquery/jquery.js

They did not have any versioning in there but how did it append v=2.2.1 in the head

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *If I do like this resources/js/1_0_0/mainscript.js*
>
> *It does not work. It says RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND*

This will work if you specify `js` as library name.

```html
<h:outputScript library="js" name="mainscript.js" />
```

However, this is not the proper usage of a resource library. Rather introduce one.

```
resources/default/1_0_0/js/mainscript.js
```

Then you can specify it as follows:

```html
<h:outputScript library="default" name="js/mainscript.js" />
```

---

> *They did not have any versioning in there but how did it append v=2.2.1 in the head*

It's done by `PrimeResource` which kicks in on resource requests with `ln=primefaces` parameter. Its `getRequestPath()` has the following implementation:

```
@Override
public String getRequestPath() {
    return super.getRequestPath() + "&amp;v=" + Constants.VERSION;
}
```

Where `Constants` is the PrimeFaces specific constants file which is updated with every PF version.

Comment: I got it, I messed up the path previously I had something like this resources/js/default/mainscript.js. Then I changed it to resources/js/default/1_0_0/mainscript.js and referring it to like this <h:outputScript library="js" name="default/mainscript.js" /> which did not work. Upon seeing your answer I changed it to resources/js/1_0_0/default/mainscript.js and it worked. Thank you!! And this is same as using this <h:outputScript library="default" name="js/mainscript.js" /> right? Just the library names swapped.

Comment: The library must represent a "theme"/"module", not the "content type". Using `library="js"`, `library="css"`, etc is a smell and indicates misunderstanding of the meaning of the `library` attribute.

Comment: Note that primefaces removed resource versioning in v3.3 due to performances issues in mojarra -- see [primefaces issue#3705](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3705) and [mojarra issue#2494](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2494)

Comment: Does the highest-version pickup only work for resources in a war? I tried putting the resources in a jar's META-INF/resources/library/1_0_0/... folder and placed that jar in my WEB-INF/lib but it didn't work. Moving the resources from the jar to the war worked. Also, putting the version as part of the name and keeping the resources in the jar worked too.