# How to force browser to reload h:outputScript resource?

Tags: jsf, resources, versioning

The JS file `extra.js` is included as follows:

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="extra.js"  />
```

I am facing issue of browser caching. Many times, I will not get the updated copy.

In plain HTML, we used to append version number or random number with JS URL like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yyy.zzzz.net/js/tryjs?v=1234"></script>
where v is the version number.
```

Is there any way to add some version number to the generated resource URL in `h:outputScript`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF resource versioning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929417/jsf-resource-versioning)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do one of the following

Manage the version number in one of you beans `#{myBean.myVersion}` and append it to you js file in `h:outputScript`

Like this:

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="extra.js?#{myBean.myVersion}/>
```

or rename your js file to include the `#{myBean.myVersion}` as a part of its name like this

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="extra.#{myBean.myVersion}.js/>
```

---

Also you can take a look at this : [Resources (Library) In JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/resources-library-in-jsf-2-0/)