# Problem with CSS - Not load latest version

Tags: primefaces

I'm using Primefaces ver 6.2. I've recently installed "Serenity" theme for my application. Since then I'm facing an issue with CSS: it seems that the application loads the cached version of CSS instead of the latest one.

I've found a guide that suggest a solution, but it doesn't work ([JSF resource versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929417/jsf-resource-versioning); [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)).

I use this method to include the CSS file:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="serenity-layout" name="css/layout-blue.css"/>
```

I use Primefaces ver. 6.2 and TomCat ver. 9

These are my [Project Folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4ttj.jpg)

Comment: I know it's a stupid question, but did you cleaned your browser's cache?

Comment: the cached version of which css? And how is the version detected or passed on?

Comment: @OscarPérez Cleaning the browser's cache it's not the solution. I need an automatic detection of the new CSS version when I upload it.

Comment: I mean, you stated you recently added Serenity, so it can't be about that? Or is it

Comment: @Kukeltje we faced this issue after implementing "Serenity". Everytime I deploy a new version on my server, it doesn't work on the web application. It still loads the old one

Comment: how (and why) do you each time deploy a new version of 'Serenity'?

Comment: @Kukeltje I don't deploy a new version of Serenity, I just update the CSS

Comment: ok, so it is not serenity related at all but just 'css updates not read' Did you check the http requests? Is the browser using the locally cached version? Or does it get the full css, just the old one? Debug things like this. And how do you update the css? By saving it in an ide? Is it deployed then on the server? Or do you do a 'package', create a war and deploy that? Please try to be as explicit as possible. Now it takes to much time to get things like this all clear (and narrow down the problem)

Comment: @Kukeltje I update the CSS in an ide and deploy the war on the server

Comment: What about all the other questions I posted in my previous comment? And is it a problem with ALL css, or just the Serenity things