# Unable to add Jquery in XHTML

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 3.3 with JSF 2.0 and I tried to include Jquery in my Facelet using

`<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js"></h:outputScript>`

However I am getting something like this when I view the source code.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="RES_NOT_FOUND"></script>`

I have searched in several posts over here itself and the best I found is the code I am using. So how can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery is already included on every page where you have primefaces components.
No need to include again.

However if you need a version which differs from primefaces just put the script tag into your `<h:head>` like:

```
<h:head>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</h:head>
```

If you have to include script file from your resources see [How to include JavaScript files by h:outputScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093032/how-to-include-javascript-files-by-houtputscript)