# How to include JavaScript file in JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf

he truth is that the code is small since I am learning, but I can not make it work, I have already touched other issues about this and I have not found a solution

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <h:head>
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-last.js" />
    </h:head>

    <div id="header">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <div class="medio">MANAGER DX2</div>
        <div class="fin"> </div>

    </div>

    <h:body>
        <div class="body">
            <div class="upbody">
                <div></div>
                <div>
                    <a href="logout.xhtml" class="_btnlnk">Salir</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container">
            </div>
        </div>

    </h:body>   


</html>
```

I also add some images with error and be able to provide more information

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: What's the stacktrace? Your use of outputScript is correct. Have you checked the rendered HTML to verify if the script has actually been included?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include JavaScript files by h:outputScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093032/how-to-include-javascript-files-by-houtputscript)

Comment: Maybe you will find answer in this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093032/how-to-include-javascript-files-by-houtputscript