# Select element with double dot in id, error: "#octo:cat" is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, d3.js, selector

Given an svg with an existing `id="kvg:StrokeNumbers_07425"`,

```
<g id="kvg:StrokeNumbers_07425" style="font-size:8;fill:blue;">...</g>
```

I do the following :

```
d3.select("#kvg:StrokeNumbers_07425").attr("style","fill:red;");
```

and get the following error message :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 
'#kvg:StrokeNumbers_07425' is not a valid selector.
```

It's likely due to the `:`.

**What should I do to make it work?**

---

**EDIT:** http://jsfiddle.net/0v7jjpdd/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape the `:` as such

```
d3.select("#kvg\\:StrokeNumbers_07425").attr("style","fill:red;");
```

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/bhh874sh/)

Comment: Hahaha. Didn't know we could do that. Thanks you & valided.