# JSF ui:include and getElementById

Tags: javascript, jsf

I'm writing the ui:composition xhtml file to include in different pages using ui:include. It looks like there's no way I can refer to the tags from javascript in this file using getElementById, as the tag ids might be prepended with the form id from the parent page. Is there a workaround?

Found this answer after I posted the question. It helped!
[Acquire full prefix for a component clientId inside naming containers with JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501022/acquire-full-prefix-for-a-component-clientid-inside-naming-containers-with-jsf-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var elem = document.querySelector( '[id$="-test"]' );
```

where `test` is the ID without the prefix, and `-` is the prefix separator.

The above code will select the element which "id" attribute ends with `"-test"` (e.g. `<div id="form1-test">...</div>`).

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/8kyb2/

Note that `querySelector()` paired with an attribute-ends-with selector performs slower than `getElementById()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use [Apache's Tomahawk Components](https://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/index.html), and specify `forceId="true"`, tag ids will remain unchanged. E.g.:

`<t:inputText id="name" forceId="true" value="#{myBean.property}" />`

will result in an `<input type="text" id="name" ... / >`.