# Obtaining the clientId of the parent of a JSF2 composite component

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component

I've got the following code:

```
<h:dataTable id="dt" value="#{somelist}" var="entry">
    <h:column>
        #{entry.title}
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <h:commandLink id="lnk">
           <mycomp:doSomething id="dummy" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

My composite component (mycomp:doSomething) looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

    <composite:interface>
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation >     
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // #{component.parent.clientId}
        </script>        
    </composite:implementation>
</html>
```

I would expect the output (`#{component.parent.clientId}`) to be something similar to this: `dt:0:lnk` but instead it returns `dt:0:dummy` i.e. the client ID of the composite component.

How do I get the ID of the real parent tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use #{cc.parent.clientId} instead. All content inside composite:implementation is inside a UIPanel that is on a facelet inside the composite component base instance, which usually is a NamingContainer.

**UPDATE:** Checking the code, cc.parent resolves the parent composite component instead of the immediate parent. It seems to be an old implementation detail, but it is not mentioned in the spec. The solution proposed in this answer does not work :(.

See http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/jsr-314-open-mirror/2010-February/002474.html

You can bypass the resolution of cc.parent, providing a custom component class extending UINamingContainer and adding this:

```
<composite:interface componentType="my.custom.ComponentBaseClass">
```

then add a getter like

```
public UIComponent getImmediateParent()
{
     return getParent();
}
```

and finally use #{cc.immediateParent.clientId}. It should work in this way.

Comment: #{cc.parent.clientId} returns an empty string (or nothing)

Comment: #{cc.parent.clientId} works if the outer component (parent) is also a composite component. But if it is an <h:commandLink /> like my example above, it doesn't return anything, in fact cc.parent returns null.

Comment: It works by using implementing a UINamingContainer for the component like you've described. Thanks!