# Should a composite component really require namingcontainer interface?

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component

I want to create a composite componet that can iterate with others. The problem is that composite componet is a namingcontainer and a simple selectOnMenu change and refresh other selectOnMenu do not is possible because "id" given to selectOnMenu is `combo1:combo` and can't see `combo2:combo`.

The best situation would be `form1:combo1` and `form1:combo2`, then, combo1 and combo2 uses uinamingcontainer of `h:form`.
This link talks about this but no solution.
https://cwiki.apache.org/MYFACES/create-a-non-namingcontainer-composite-component.html

Another try but don't works. `p:commandbutton` can't see id of div inside of CC.
[Obtaining the clientId of the parent of a JSF2 composite component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477578/obtaining-the-clientid-of-the-parent-of-a-jsf2-composite-component)

```
<p:commandButton value="asd" partialSubmit="true" process="@this" update="fooId"/>  
    <cf:label id="fooId" title="xxxxx" />[index.xhtml]




<composite:interface componentType="RootComponent" preferred="false">
    <composite:attribute name="title" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
<div id="#{cc.immediateParent.clientId}:#{cc.id}">
#{currentDate}
<h:panelGroup id="#{cc.clientId}" layout="block">
    <p:outputLabel id="#{cc.clientId}_lb" value="#{cc.attrs.title}">
        <composite:insertChildren />
    </p:outputLabel>
</h:panelGroup>
</div>
</composite:implementation>[label.xhtml](compositecomponent)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Should a composite component really require namingcontainer interface?*

Yes. Otherwise you would end up with "Duplicate component ID" errors coming from the composite component implementation when using multiple of them in the same parent naming container.

If you're absolutely positive that you don't want a `NamingContainer` based component, then rather create a tag file instead. It only requires some `.taglib.xml` boilerplate.

#### See also:

- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen)

---

> *Another try but don't works. `p:commandbutton` can't see id of div inside of CC*

Your composite implementation is invalid. In order to reference a composite properly by ajax, you need a plain HTML `<div>` or a `<span>` with exactly the ID of `#{cc.clientId}`.

E.g.

```
<composite:implementation>
    <div id="#{cc.clientId}">
        #{currentDate}
        <h:panelGroup layout="block">
            <p:outputLabel id="#{cc.clientId}_lb" value="#{cc.attrs.title}">
                <composite:insertChildren />
            </p:outputLabel>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </div>
</composite:implementation>
```

*(I have by the way the impression that the `<h:panelGroup>` is superfluous, you can safely omit it; further the `id="#{cc.clientId}_lb"` can better be `id="label"` or something to minimize repetition/duplication)*

#### See also:

- [JSF Updating Composite Component (Primefaces)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690635/jsf-updating-composite-component-primefaces)
- [Is it possible to update non-JSF components (plain HTML) with JSF ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009174/jsf-update-with-ajax-non-jsf-things)

Comment: And now is like below:
...<h:form id="myForm">
 <cf:label id="fooId1" update=":myForm:fooId2" />
 <cf:label id="fooId2" update=":myForm:fooId1" />...</h:form> 
...<composite:interface>
 <composite:attribute name="update" />
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
<div id="#{cc.clientId}">
 #{currentDate}--
 <p:commandButton partialSubmit="true" process="@this" update="#{cc.attrs.update}"/>
</div>
</composite:implementation>...

I really need to put ":myForm:xxxxx" for "ajax update" another field? h:form already is a uinamingcontainer, why need I more?